# How to use packaged assets with Flask-Assets

Tags: python, flask, webassets, flask-assets

How can I bundle assets using Flask-Assets that exist outside of Flasks default static/ directory?

- I have `npm install` downloading assets into `bower_components/`
- I have other javascripts that exist in `javascripts/`
- I am using Flasks app factory pattern, and no matter how I've tried configuring Flask-Assets - I cannot get around the `assets instance not bound to an application, and no application in current context` exception.

Any help would be appreciated, especially if you can just give me an example on how to manage raw + packaged assets outside your apps static/ directory :P

### app structure

```
app/
    static/
    __init__.py
    assets.py
javascripts/
    app.js
bower_components/
    jquery.js
    jquery,pjax,js
```

### app/assets.py

```
from flask.ext.assets import Bundle, Environment

js = Bundle(
    'bower_components/jquery.js',
    'bower_components/jquery.pjax.js',
    'javascripts/app.js'
    filters='jsmin',
    output='static/packed.js'
)

assets = Environment()

assets.register('js_all', js)
```

### app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from app.assets import assets

app = Flask(__name__)
assets.init_app(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked Flask-Assets source and found this in the docstring of `FlaskResolver` class:

> If a `Environment.load_path` is set, it is used to look up source files, replacing the Flask system. Blueprint prefixes are no longer resolved.

So you need to do the following in app/init.py:

```py
from os.path import abspath, join

app = Flask(__name__)
assets.load_path = abspath(join(app.root_path, '..'))
assets.init_app(app)
```